# New software can't be installed: Dependency Problems

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-center

I got this error when installing PyCharm and it start software can't be installed. I left it at that. But now I'm unable to install any new software because of broken dependencies.

```
installArchives() failed: Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 333416 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../oracle-java9-installer_9b102+9b102arm-1~webupd8~0_all.deb ...

oracle-license-v1-1 license could not be presented
try 'dpkg-reconfigure debconf' to select a frontend other than noninteractive

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/oracle-java9-installer_9b102+9b102arm-1~webupd8~0_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/oracle-java9-installer_9b102+9b102arm-1~webupd8~0_all.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pycharm:
 pycharm depends on java6-runtime | java7-runtime; however:
  Package java6-runtime is not installed.
  Package java7-runtime is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package pycharm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15282410/

What should I do now?

Comment: Try running this from the terminal `sudo dpkg-reconfigure debconf` and then edit the question and include the result..

Comment: Uh. Nothing happened.  I was asked about the interface to you and the kind of questions to be asked (high, critical) and it closed.

Comment: How about `sudo dpkg-reconfigure pycharm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these commands

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -a --configure
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```