# Can't install new software in the server

Tags: apt, server, package-management, kernel, vsftpd

I'm trying to install vsftpd on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but when I run `apt-get install vsftpd` I get this error:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic but it is not going to be installed

Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-39-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic but it is not going to be installed or

linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-39-generic but it is not going to be installed

linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-42-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic but it is not going to be installed or

linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-42-generic but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried run `apt --fix-broken install` and `apt-get install -f vsftpd` but with no sucess.

I looked these answers but the solution didn't worked for me:
[Can't install new software/packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789137/cant-install-new-software-packages)
[New software can't be installed: Dependency Problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742126/new-software-cant-be-installed-dependency-problems)

**Update:**

`df -h` output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        39G  7.3G   30G  21% /
devtmpfs        989M     0  989M   0% /dev
tmpfs           992M     0  992M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           992M  680K  992M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           992M     0  992M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      232M  224M     0 100% /boot
tmpfs           199M     0  199M   0% /run/user/0
```

`df -i` output:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/root      2537760 337826 2199934   14% /
devtmpfs        253100    434  252666    1% /dev
tmpfs           253889      1  253888    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           253889    606  253283    1% /run
tmpfs           253889      4  253885    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           253889     18  253871    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1       62248    326   61922    1% /boot
tmpfs           253889     10  253879    1% /run/user/0
```

`apt-cache policy linux-image-generic` output:

```
linux-image-generic:
  Installed: 4.15.0.42.44
  Candidate: 4.15.0.42.44
  Version table:
 *** 4.15.0.42.44 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.15.0.20.23 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     4.4.0.139.145 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
```

`uname -r` output:

```
4.15.0-36-generic
```

**Update 2:**
I try this command:

```
dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ^ii
```

it shows only one kernel:

```
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic          4.15.0-36.39  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
```

When I try to remove:

```
apt-get remove linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic
```

The return is:

```
ou might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-36-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-36-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-39-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-39-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-42-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-42-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for a single magic incantation. There isn't one.  You must *understand* the problem in order to solve it. Happily, this looks like a rather easy problem. Please update your question with the complete output of `df -h` and `df -i` and `apt-cache policy linux-image-generic` and `uname -r`

Comment: @user535733 I've updated the question and thank you for the advice =)

Comment: @user535733 I follow the link but the solution didn't work

Comment: If you are having a rotten time understanding why a full /boot is a Bad Thing, and need one-on-one tutoring, then try our sibling site www.ubuntuforums.org. AskUbuntu's format is Question/Answer, and is poorly suited toward conversation and tutoring. You provided enough information for us to clearly determine the problem, but it seems like perhaps you don't quite understand the problem or the solution(s).